# DIV width: 100% creates a space when is the window resize to a size less than major DIV

Tags: css

I got a div #header width: 1000px;

```
#header {
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
height: 164px;
}
```

A div #main-container in full-width

```
#main-container {
height: 278px;
background: url(images/mainbg.png);
width: 100%;
}
```

But when I resize my window to a size less than 1000px setted on header, the #main-container creates a empty space.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zcmmpf&s=5

I want to remove this space, and let the #main-container have full-width

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but did you try using `max-width: 1000px;` in your `#header` instead of `width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct CSS behavior.

For example, consider your HMTL snippet:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

with the following CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 164px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#main-container {
    height: 278px;
    background: pink url('http://placekitten.com/2000/278') top center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5xwRu/

For pages wider than 1000px, your header is centered as you expect.

Your background image fills up width of the page because the `#main-container` has 100% width.

As you reduce the page width to less than 1000px, you will see a horizontal scrolling bar appear because the fixed width header is too wide to fit in the view port, which triggers
an overflow condition.

In this situation, the CSS engine creates some white space the right of `#main-container` since `#main-container` has a computed width less than 1000px and it fills up the view port width (which is less than 1000px), which does not include the space created for the overflowing content.

You can fix this a number of ways, but it depends in part on what you want to do.

You could set a minimum width as follows:

```css
#main-container {
    height: 278px;
    background: pink url('http://placekitten.com/2000/278') top center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

See example 2 in the demo fiddle.

**Note:** You may have a wrapper container to which the CSS property `overflow: hidden` is applied.  If this is the case you may not see a horizontal scrolling bar.